# command spawnl() not executed

Tags: c++

I have a code that is executable without error messages but it seems like it denies to run the code

I call by the "spawnl" command. This is my code and I receive "error=-1". I tried may different ways to solve the situation but I always receive the "-1" for an answer. I use Dev C++ compiler with 32bit release. My problem is to call the other program, sending the name of the file.

```cpp
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <graphics.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <conio.h>
  #include <process.h>
  #include <ctype.h>
  #include <dir.h>
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <dos.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <stddef.h>

 void translate_to_ascii_files(),
      save_mesh_data(),
      make_no(),
      give_names();
 

 int load_patches(char *);

FILE *memco ;
int outnod[400] ;
float r_vector[21][21][3],cx[500],cy[500],cz[500] ;
int NOP1,NOP2;  /* Number Of Points */
int patches;
char nams[26][26];
int num_of_files;
int kk,nv,nh,exnod,totnod ;
int no[4][400];
char filename[26];
void *buf;
COORD coord= {0,0};
HANDLE  hConsole;
using namespace std;    // std::cout, std::cin


void gotoxy(int x,int y)  {
     coord.X=x;
     coord.Y=y;
     SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),coord);
     }

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
        char com_nam[26];
       int counter1,counter2,i;
       int error;

       system("cls");
       give_names();

       printf("give the final filename:");scanf("%s",filename);
     for(patches=1;patches<=num_of_files;patches++) {
      strcpy(com_nam,nams[patches]);
     load_patches(com_nam);    /*   load patches for meshing*/
       i=1;
     for(counter1=0;counter1<=NOP1;counter1++)   {
     for(counter2=0;counter2<=NOP2;counter2++)   {
    cx[i]=r_vector[counter1][counter2][0];
    cy[i]=r_vector[counter1][counter2][1];
    cz[i]=r_vector[counter1][counter2][2];
    i=i+1;
              }
       }

   
     nh=NOP1+1;nv=NOP2+1;
     make_no();
     save_mesh_data();


    if(argc ==1){
   error=spawnl(P_WAIT,"c:\\cpprog\\unitsrf.exe","",filename,NULL);   
   if (error ==0) {
   else {printf ("error=%d\n",error); system("PAUSE");
     }            }

    else{gotoxy(2,11);printf("error=%s\n\n",argv[1]);
  system("PAUSE");
             }
         }  translate_to_ascii_files();
    }
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's currently all over the place which makes it hard for others and for you to both read the code and to spot many types of obvious error.

Comment: Examine `errno` after the call; that will tell you what the error is.  See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/spawnl-wspawnl) for info on possible `errno` values and their meaning.

Comment: As said by kaylum, indent this mess. It's easy: https://techiedelight.com/tools/clike

Comment: I'm very sorry about the mesh of my upload. I'll try to fix it

Comment: You mean after this call ,
 "error=spawnl(P_WAIT,"c:\\cpprog\\unitsrf.exe","",filename,NULL);" ?

Comment: The problem is in this area of the code:  if(argc ==1){
       error=spawnl(P_WAIT,"c:\\cpprog\\unitsrf.exe","",filename,NULL);   
       if (error ==0) {
       else {printf ("error=%d\n",error); system("PAUSE");
         }            }

        else{gotoxy(2,11);printf("error=%s\n\n",argv[1]);
      system("PAUSE");

Comment: Especially here :     
     spawnl(P_WAIT,"c:\\cpprog\\unitsrf.exe","",filename,NULL);   
 When i call this subroutine. It seems to me that the code runs over it and ignores the command, but doesn't give a feed back why. The code terminates with an error"=-1" but normally. The compilation process doesn't stops, neither gives a warning.

Comment: Please, don't add `C` tag to code that is not `C`, but requires the `c++` extensions.

Comment: This code was initially written in c and now i'd like to transform it in c++. Till last week was fully functional in Turbo c